# Ударение в заимствованных фамилиях

Tags: фонетика

Постановка ударений в заимствованных словах - вещь сложная. Если "чужое" ударение не соответствует привычкам носителей языка-приемника, оно постепенно подстроится под "новый" язык. Но можно ли это же правило применять к фамилиям и другим именам собственным?
Хотя, конечно, и здесь бывают самые странные искажения. Чего стоит только "пролив Гудзон" (какое-то индейское на слух имя!), который на поверку оказывается тривиальным "Хадсоном".

Конкретно у меня вызывает сомнения сэр Ньютон. Как человек, знающий английский, я, конечно, говорю "НьЮтон". Но известную формулу называю "НьютОна-Лейбница", оправдывая себя тем, чт это профессиональный жаргон.

Как же все-таки правильно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Кстати, я задавала уже подобный вопрос, только относился он к Флор**и**де, которая на самом деле Фл**о**рида.
Думаю, что жестких правил тут быть не может. Иноязычные слова всегда коверкали (взять хоты бы наши имена, которые в греческом, римском и др. оригиналах мало походили на привычных нам Юриев, Николаев, Иванов и Марий). Заимствованные слова произносили так, как было удобнее, как привык поворачиваться язык. Плюс, как мне кажется, работал эффект "испорченного телефона": кто-то не так расслышал, а кто-то плохо запомнил. Вот и превратились Хадсон в Гудзон, доктор Уотсон в доктора Ватсона, а Инглэнд - в Англию)))
Короче говоря, правило тут одно: как слово исторически легло на язык, так и правильно.
Кстати, мы учили уравнение Нь**ю**тона-Лейбница)))

Comment: Да, наверное, так. Но все-таки Ньютон - это конкретный человек, весьма уважаемый. Впрочем, ему уже все равно!

Comment: Ну, в моей фамилии тоже постоянно коверкают ударение. Но, как говорится, главное, чтобы человек был хороший))

Answer (score 0):

Разумеется Нь**ю**тона-Лейбница. Здесь нет никакого жаргона.
Лучше бы разобрались с полиномами Ч**е**бышева, который на самом деле Чебышёв.
Вполне себе русский Пафнутий Львович.  Вот здесь действитеьно закреплённое недоразумение.
Это я ктому, что неча на иностранщину кивать.

Comment: Ну, лично я с "Чебышёвым" обхожусь правильно. Осталось привыкнуть говорить "Ляйбниц", "Кляйн", как делал один наш профессор.  

А если возможен "Лейбниц", то почему не быть "НьютОну"? Ноя исправляюсь!